# 2.2 and 4.1.2 differences in SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have this code:

```
public static String WEEK_DAY_SHORT = "c";

public static String getWeekDay(int day) {
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day + 2);

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(WEEK_DAY_SHORT + ", " + DATE);
    return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

when I run this method on 4.1.2 everything is okay and I get outputs like `Mo;Di;Mi;...`
But when I run this on 2.2 I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character - 'c'
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:379)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:428)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:499)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:363)
        at
de.MayerhoferSimon.Vertretungsplan.Utils.DateHelper.getWeekDay(DateHelper.java:54)
```

the same is when I try `"cc"` for a short dayname or `"cccc"` for a long dayname.

Are there differences in the `SimpleDateFormat` class between 2.2 and 4.1.2 ?
And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "EEEE" for the dayname, and "EEE" for short dayname